# Angular? throwing unexpected token because of less?

Tags: angularjs, less, systemjs, jspm

I'm using:

> JSPM, SystemJS and Angular

I can't import less files without running into a series of errors:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'text' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [status text] starting at [text].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$parse/syntax?p0=text&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=8&p3=status%20text&p4=text
    at eval (http://localhost:8002/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.0/angular.js:68:12)
    at Object.AST.throwError (http://localhost:8002/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.0/angular.js:13816:11)
    at Object.AST.ast (http://localhost:8002/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.0/angular.js:13586:12)
    at Object.ASTCompiler.compile (http://localhost:8002/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.0/angular.js:14040:31)
    at Parser.parse (http://localhost:8002/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.0/angular.js:14927:29)
    at $parse (http://localhost:8002/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.0/angular.js:15035:39)
    at $interpolate (http://localhost:8002/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.0/angular.js:11770:25)
    at addTextInterpolateDirective (http://localhost:8002/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.0/angular.js:9282:27)
    at collectDirectives (http://localhost:8002/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.0/angular.js:8350:11)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8002/jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.0/angular.js:8145:22) undefined
```

[image]

I've read a lot online and found that for some people it was the encoding of the file, but I've tried several things including the one below with no luck:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
```

Any ideas why is that happening? 
Please, let me know if there are any parts of my code that could be of help.

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think this message has something to do with less or css? It seems you have an incorrect expression in your HTML template. Where does `status text` appear in your seource code?

Comment: @JBNizet when I debug I can see the less files are throwing the error. Check the new image.

Comment: @JBNizet I just added two pictures for a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You seem to think there's a bug in Angular. There's 99.999% chance that the bug is in your code. What code causes this error to happen?

Comment: @JBNizet it was a comment on one of the less files =/ I don't know why it was trying to parse the comment, but it was...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a comment!! I have no idea why, but Angular was trying to parse the comment:

```
/*
---------------------------------------
A status badge.
---------------------------------------

Usage:

  <span class="badge badge-status">
    {{status text}}
  </div>

---------------------------------------
*/
```

I solved it by removing the comment.